# PHPUnit - Not seeing code coverage on simple function

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where in my test, my assert passes.. but neither my expects() passes, nor am I seeing coverage executing in the resulting code coverage generated html.

error: Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

I'm starting with a very basic example (below). I must be missing something obvious with phpunit that I haven't wrapped my head around with yet, apparently. I double-checked that the function I'm trying to test is in fact a public function.

At this point, I would just like to be able to see some coverage executing in the generated code coverage html.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
public function returnVal()
{
  return 5;
}

public function test_returnVal()
{
    $testVal = 5;
    $controllerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $controllerMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('testReturnVal')
        ->with($testVal);

    $testResult = $controllerMock->testReturnVal($testVal);
    $this->assertEquals($testResult, $testVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not see any code coverage, as you never actually execute the returnVal() function.  Your test suite uses a Mock which does not call the original function, but it references a Mock function (testReturnVal) instead.

```
$controllerMock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('testReturnVal')
    ->with($testVal);
```

When testing, Mocks are handy for hiding external dependencies and keeping a known state.  However, for simply functions (add 2 numbers for instance) you can simply create the object and call the code.

For your situation, simply add an additional test into the test code:

```
public function test_RealReturnVal()
{
     $TestObject = new MyClass();
     $this->assertEquals(5, $TestObject->returnVal());
}
```

This new test will actually call your real code and execute the returnVal() call.  This will cause the code coverage to show these lines as executed.

Comment: I accepted your answer because executing the real code would fix the issue.. however, due to various dependencies I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: The problem ended up actually being, and I'm shaking my head as I type.. due to TYPO in the getMockBuilder call. ie MyClass vs Myclass (more obscure, actually). There was no error produced so it took a while to track down..

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.5+ you could use `MyClass::class` instead of `'MyClass'` in the call to `$this->getMockBuilder()`. I've started doing that everywhere to eliminate typos on my part but also to facilitate using my IDE's refactoring tools to rename classes and (sometimes) move them into new namespaces.